# itemize inside tabularx seems to break exam class gradetable

Tags: itemize, tabularx, exam, gradetable

I'm using the exam class.  If I use the itemize environment inside a tabularx, LaTeX gives me warnings when I use the gradetable command:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `question@1' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
```

and

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

The compiled document puts "??" instead of the question number in the grade table.

Minimal example follows - any suggestions welcome:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\addpoints

\begin{document}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Note that the question is also not numbered.  Removing the gradetable instruction removes the warning, but the question is still not numbered.

Comment: What is the idea behind using `itemize` inside a `tabularx`? Can you elaborate? There may be other better ways for it. BTW put a `\mbox{}` like `\mbox{}\begin{tabularx}` if you insist.

Comment: The question needs an itemize, but the question must be presented in two languages - the actual situation has two columns, one for each language - hence the tabularx.

Comment: By the way, the mbox tip worked (someone else had also since suggested by email - although it's unclear to me why it should fix it.  It seems to me the example should work without it.  So I guess the question now is whether my usage is non-standard enough to disqualify this from being a "bug"?